# Generate Eventhandler of unknown type while running

Tags: c#, silverlight

is it possible to generate an eventhandler while running?
I want to do something like that:

```
public bool addCallback(string name, Delegate Callback)
{
   EventInfo ei = DataProxy.GetType().GetEvent(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
   if (ei == null)
      return false;
   ei.AddEventHandler(DataProxy, Callback);
   //now I want to add an Eventhandler, which removes the Callback and this new Eventhandler itsself
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am not 100% sure I understand what you are going to hook your generated event handler to from the example, but here's the easiest way I know of for creating an event handler)

Depends on your platform and trust level. The most flexible way of doing it is to use `Emit` to generate the method (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx)).

However, I found a relatively easy to use and good alternative to be generated Linq expressions (here's the [namespace help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb506649.aspx)).

The idea is fairly simple:

1. Use the various Expression-derived classes you can see in the namespace to define what your callback is doing. In this case, you want to generate something that calls `.RemoveEventHandler` (I am guessing) on the `ei` instance (specifically, you will use the [ConstantExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.constantexpression.aspx) to create a ref to your `ei` variable and to your Callback parameter and a [MethodCallExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.aspx) to create a call to the `RemoveDataHandler` method).
2. Once you create the expression that does what you need, you need to create a delegate (Lambda) out of it (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268052.aspx))
3. Almost done. You still need to compile the lambda, which you do by calling `.Compile` on the object you got from the previous step ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928.aspx))

Edit: This is a Windows console example of a dynamically generated delegate that removes itself. Note that WP7 Linq expression support is more limited than .NET 4.0 and so you will need to adjust it (make helper methods that will do some of the work and call them from the expression instead of what I did).

Edit2: BTW: The mechanism by which the lambda can remove itself, is to create another lambda that returns a local variable that is of that type. After creating the lambda, save it to the local variable and run the code (I am not sure if this would have worked without the secondary lambda)

Edit3: No - you have to use the delegate trick, otherwise, the constant gets "frozen" and will not update as you would want it to. So the code as is works.

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
}

public class EventContainer
{
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;

    public void Fire()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Firing");
        if (MyEvent != null)
        {
            MyEvent(this, new MyEventArgs());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Fired");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventContainer container = new EventContainer();
        var adder = container.GetType().GetMethod("add_MyEvent");
        var remover = container.GetType().GetMethod("remove_MyEvent");

        object self = null;
        Func<object> getSelf = () => self;

        var block = Expression.Block(
            // Call something to output to console.
            Expression.Call(
                null,
                typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }),
                Expression.Constant("Event called")),
            // Now call the remove_Event method.
            Expression.Call(
                Expression.Constant(container), // passing the container as "this"
                remover, // And the remover as the method info
                Expression.Convert( // we need to cast the result of getSelf to the correct type to pass as an argument
                    Expression.Invoke( // For the parameter (what to convert), we need to call getSelf
                        Expression.Constant(getSelf)), // So this is a ref to getSelf
                    adder.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType) // finally, say what to convert to.
               ) 
           );

        // Create a lambda of the correct type.
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(
            adder.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType, 
            block, 
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(object)), 
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyEventArgs)));
        var del = lambda.Compile();

        // Make sure "self" knows what the delegate is (so our generated code can remove it)
        self = del;


        // Add the event.
        adder.Invoke(container, new object[] { del });

        // Fire once - see that delegate is being called.
        container.Fire();

        // Fire twice - see that the delegate was removed.
        container.Fire();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint, it was very useful. Sadly I cannot vote up this answer caused by lack of reputation.
Still my problem isn't solved completely. To make clear, what I am trying to achieve, I will rephrase my explanation of the method. The method should add the `Delegate` defined by the parameter `Callback` as an Eventhandler to the Event, named by the parameter `name` of the object `DataContext`. Right after that it should add an Eventhandler to the same Event of `DataContext`, which removes both the `Callback` and itsself.

Comment: Ah. For that, you want to use Reflection to find the MethodInfo that is called "add_" + name and "remove_" + name. These will be the methods that add and remove the event handler.

Comment: Please refer to my other answer here. As I said there is only one step missing. I already used reflections to add an eventhandler, which removes the Callback, but I still want the created method to removes itself from the event, do you now what I mean? In normal code it would look like that:
    Object.CallCompleted += CallCompleted;
    Object.CallCompleted += RemoveHandler;
    void RemoveHandler(object sender, CompletedEventArgs eA)
    {
    Object.CallCompleted -= CallCompleted;
    Object.CallCompleted -= RemoveHandler;
    }

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting.. Your point is that there's a chicken and egg situation here, right? How can a lambda remove itself if it doesn't have a reference to itself.... Awesome. Let me add the code to the answrer.

Comment: This helped me allot, still cannot vote up your answer though.
Had to change some parts of your code, cause ´object´ cannot be converted to ´Delegate´ nor ´Eventhandler´, so I changed ´object´ to ´Delegate´. I will post my final code soon, maybe someone could vote it up.

Comment: Don't care too much about making it the answer. But the code runs as written - tested it in console.

Comment: I am using Silverlight, maybe that's the Reason, why it wasn't possible to convert. Works fine with Delegate.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool addCallback(string name, Delegate Callback)
{
    if (DataProxy == null)
        GetDataProxy();
    EventInfo ei = DataProxy.GetType().GetEvent(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (ei == null)
        return false;
    ei.AddEventHandler(DataProxy, Callback);
    Type handlerType = ei.EventHandlerType;
    MethodInfo invokeMethod = handlerType.GetMethod("Invoke");
    ParameterInfo[] parms = invokeMethod.GetParameters();
    Type[] parmTypes = new Type[parms.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < parms.Length; i++)
    {
        parmTypes[i] = parms[i].ParameterType;
    }
    List<ParameterExpression> parameters = new List<ParameterExpression>();
    foreach(Type t in parmTypes)
    {
        parameters.Add(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(t));
    }
    ConstantExpression eventInfo = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(ei, typeof(EventInfo));
    ConstantExpression eventCallback = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(Callback, typeof(Delegate));
    ConstantExpression dataProxy = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(DataProxy, typeof(MAServiceClient));
    MethodCallExpression call = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(eventInfo, ei.GetType().GetMethod("RemoveEventHandler"), dataProxy, eventCallback);
    //add to Expression.Body the call, which removes the new Eventhandler itsself
    ei.AddEventHandler(DataProxy, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(ei.EventHandlerType, call, parameters).Compile());
    return true;
}
```

This is what my method looks like right now. There is just one step missing, where the new Eventhandler (created by `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(ei.EventHandlerType, call, parameters).Compile()`) removes itsself (see comment).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Shahar Prish I came up with the following code:

```
using ex = System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

    public static bool addCallback(string name, Delegate Callback)
    {
        if (DataProxy == null)
            GetDataProxy();
        EventInfo ei = DataProxy.GetType().GetEvent(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (ei == null)
            return false;
        ei.AddEventHandler(DataProxy, Callback);
        Type handlerType = ei.EventHandlerType;
        MethodInfo removeMethod = ei.GetType().GetMethod("RemoveEventHandler");
        MethodInfo invokeMethod = handlerType.GetMethod("Invoke");
        ParameterInfo[] parms = invokeMethod.GetParameters();
        Type[] parmTypes = new Type[parms.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parms.Length; i++)
        {
            parmTypes[i] = parms[i].ParameterType;
        }
        List<ParameterExpression> parameters = new List<ParameterExpression>();
        foreach(Type t in parmTypes)
        {
            parameters.Add(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(t));
        }
        Delegate self = null;
        Func<Delegate> getSelf = () => self;
        ConstantExpression eventInfo = ex.Expression.Constant(ei, typeof(EventInfo));
        ConstantExpression eventCallback = ex.Expression.Constant(Callback, typeof(Delegate));
        ConstantExpression dataProxy = ex.Expression.Constant(DataProxy, typeof(MAServiceClient));
        MethodCallExpression removeCallback = ex.Expression.Call(eventInfo, removeMethod, dataProxy, eventCallback);
        MethodCallExpression removeSelf = ex.Expression.Call(eventInfo, removeMethod, dataProxy, ex.Expression.Invoke(ex.Expression.Constant(getSelf)));
        BlockExpression block = ex.Expression.Block(removeCallback, removeSelf);
        LambdaExpression lambda = ex.Expression.Lambda(ei.EventHandlerType, block, parameters);
        Delegate del = lambda.Compile();
        self = del;
        ei.AddEventHandler(DataProxy, del);
        lambda = ex.Expression.Lambda(ei.EventHandlerType, block, parameters);
        return true;
    }
```

As I said before, this method should add the `Eventhandler` passed by `Delegate Callback` to the `Event` named `string name` of the `static MAServiceClient DataProxy` and remove it after it was called (and the `Eventhandler` which removes the Callback itsself).